# How can you dynamically grant permissions to an AWS Lambda function to access resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dynamic, resources, aws-lambda, policy

I have created a lambda function in AWS for the purpose of accessing resources based on a lookup.

For example: I want to query a dynamoDB table FOO_BAR for a customer FOO via the API Gateway.

The request comes in, I identify its table FOO that's required and I want to be able to apply a policy to my current lambda function/session that will grant access to the FOO_BAR table.

My problem is: for the lambda function to be able to query table FOO_BAR, the execution role configured when creating the lambda function needs to have read access and I don't want to grant any wild card access to this role.

The API used goes through a custom authorizer and here I have applied a policy to access the APIs; I was also hoping that I could get my lambda function to also inherit the policy generated by the custom Authorizer.

Can you dynamically grant permissions to a lambda function to access resources?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Lambda function can't inherit permissions from your custom Authorizer.

You can grant permissions or generate new IAM credentials inside your Lambda function and use those for the DynamoDB call via separate client instance.

I'm not sure if your approach provides any security benefits over wildcard. Function that grants permissions to itself has exactly the same security level.

Comment: Thanks kixorz, I've come to the same conclusions. In my case, its turning out to be too expensive time-wise to access the resource via apis, so instead I've implemented [STS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)  and allowing direct access to the resources based on a generated policy. This cuts out the pullup/teardown time within the Lambda function. This works alot better for access to resources like SQS. User 1 gets a token via sts via our api and that token only grants access to their resource.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS.STS assumeRole function

```
/**
 * Assume Role for cross account operations
 */
assumeRole() {
    let policy = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::356035958081:role/xyzRole"
        }
    };
    let params = {
        RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::356035958081:role/xyzRole',
        RoleSessionName: 'awssdk',
        Policy: JSON.stringify(policy)
    };
    console.info("Assuming Role with params:", params);
    let sts = new AWS.STS();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sts.assumeRole(params, (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(`Could not assume role, error : ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
                reject({
                    statusCode: 400,
                    message: error["message"]
                });
            } else {
                console.log(`Successfully Assumed Role details data=${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
                resolve({
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: data
                });
            }
        })
    });

}
```

this will return  Credentials with

```
        Credentials.AccessKeyId,
        Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
        Credentials.SessionToken
```